# How do I create a link in an HTML block that dynamically inserts profile fields in the URL?

Tags: php, html, moodle

I want to be able to create a block in Moodle that links to a Google Form. But, the block needs to insert some information from the user's profile. Specifically, the username, ID number, and time. I know how to create the Google Form and use the "Fillable Link."

How can I accomplish this task? It could also be inserted into the theme's menu, too.

Comment: Please provide clear code for your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new plugin of type "block" as documented [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks).
If you only need to insert some HTML or even basic PHP stuff, you simply need two files.

1. Create a new folder inside the Moodle "blocks" directory, example `/var/www/moodle/blocks/googleform`
2. Inside this new directory, create a file named `version.php`. Example :

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
$plugin->version   = 2017051500;
$plugin->requires  = 2017050500;
$plugin->component = 'block_googleform';
```

3. In the same directory, create a `block_googleform.php` file :

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
class block_googleform extends block_base {
    public function init() {
        $this->title = get_string('pluginname', 'block_googleform');
    }

    public function get_content() {
        global $USER;
        $username = $USER->username;
        $userid = $USER->id;

        $this->content = "put your Google form here";
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

Then, visit your Moodle homepage to let the software guess you created a new plugin. Install it and try adding a block instance of type "googleform".

If you prefer rely on your theme only, you could try to use the same global $USER infos in the PHP layouts files.